# MS Lightswitch populate controls on page load

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm new to Lightswitch and am stuck on a problem I hope you could assist me with. I have a Lightswitch project which is a test to see how Lightswitch functions. The project has two screens:

**Screen 1: Survey Question screen**
This screen just lists a bunch of questions which when clicked on leads to an answer page. This page represents an object with the following properties:

> - Question text i.e. how do you feel about the weather
> - Question id: a random guid

When the user clicks on a question box, the app loads a second page which is the answer page

**Screen 2: Survey Answer screen**
This screen has a parameter passed into it which is the question id from screen 1 and the following object properties

> - Answer i.e. a textbox a person types their answer into
> - Answer Id: a random guid
> - CreatedOn: a datetime field which has the current datetime

What I'm trying to do is have the answerid and createdon fields auto populate when the form loads. I can't seem to get it to work currently. I even tried to get the Answer text control populated but still no luck.

I have tried the following approaches to simply what I'm trying to do

1. Enter the following code on the form created event for the answer page so that the answer textbox gets populated

   ```
   myapp.AddEditAnswer.created = function (screen) {
       // Write code here.
       screen.SvyAnswer.Answer = 'test';
   };
   ```
2. Enter the following code on the form when the control renders

   ```
   myapp.AddEditAnswer.Answer_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
       // Write code here.
       contentItem.value = 'test1';
   };
   ```

I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally wrong but looking at tutorials and workshops on the web I cannot see what it is.